# Error reported when calling function in Matlab main program, find a solution

Tags: function

I wrote a separate script file for the functions that need to be called in the main program. Initially, the function name and the file name of the script were the same, as shown in the red box in the figure. When running, an error message "Local function name must be different from the script name." was displayed.

So I changed the name of the script file for this function, and when I run it again, it displayed "unable to define local function "seekjbkd" because it has the same name as the file.". May I ask how to solve this problem.